# Android app code coverage without having JUnit or any other automated test case?

Tags: code-coverage, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I have an full fledged android application and its source code but there is no JUnit or any other automated test cases are available for the app. How can I do code coverage test for it?
Is Jacoco any plugin like Gradle can be helpful in this scenario?
Thanks in adavance.

Comment: The alternative name for "code coverage" is "test coverage".  If you have no tests, then your test coverage is zero, and so you have your result.  What are you expecting to get from "code coverage" with zero tests?  Most folks would say you need to write some tests, first.

Comment: My requirement is to find out unused code from the code base and There is no automated test cases available. So my question is that if I manually test the application and after executing all of the features of the application, is there any tool that could help me to figure out unused code in this way?

Comment: What you really want is a static code analysis tool which detects unused code. I believe PMD and FindBugs can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Our [Java Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html) can collect code coverage statistics regardless of how the application is exercised.  It is not dependent on any specific unit test framework (although it can work any, including none).

If you run it with tests, you get "code coverage from tests".   If you simply exercise the application manually, you get "what code does this manual operation exercise?"   If you do a thorough manual exercising of the code, you get the equivalent of "what code does all of my manual testing" exercise.